# List files from s3 greater than some lastModified date

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property method of s3 in Node JS lambda to get all objects currently. This returns all the objects upto 1000. Is there any way to get the files whose lastModified date > input last Modified date from s3 using this method?

Comment: You will need to perform that filtering _after_ receiving the list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible via the S3 API.

The best you can do is get creative with your object naming scheme, and name things in reverse alphabetical order.  Starting with something like `ZZZZZZZZZZZ`, then `ZZZZZZZZZZY`, etc.